# Deserialize with Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a nested Json object and I want to deserialize it into the Account object.

Json example:

```
   {
     "status": "OK",
     "output": {
    "accountNum": ".....",
    "customerType": ".....",
    "homeNumber": ".....",
    "homeIndicator": ".....",
    "eligible": true,
    "startDate": "2017-01-01",
    "contactDetails": {
        "firstName": ".....",
        "lastName": ".....",
        "addressStreet": ".....",
    },
    "indicators": [
        "ind1",
        "ind2",
    ],
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": ".....",
            "email": ".....",
            "model": ".....",
            "program": [
                {
                    "name": ".....",
                    "date": "....."
                },
                {
                    "name": ".....",
                    "date": "....."
                }
            ],
            "type": ".....",
            "indicators": [
                "....."
            ],
            "customer": false
        }
    ],
}
 }
```

Since it’s a nested Json I am using the following method to do that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Flux<Timed<XXXDto >> mergedMonos = Flux.fromIterable(jsonList).flatMapSequential(Function.identity());
    mergedMonos.map(timed -> mapper.valueToTree(timed.get())).collectList().subscribe(System.out::print);

@Component
public class XXXDto {

@Autowired
private Account account;

@JsonProperty("output")
private void unpackOutput(Map<String, Object> output) {
    //Account a1 = new Account();
    // this.account.setAccountNum is null 

    output.get("accountNum");
```

The problem is that I want to store the "accountNum" in the Account object but during the deserialization the inject Account is null.

I can create an instance in **unpackOutput** method but I would to see if there is another option via injection.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you give an example of the json you want to deserialise ?

Comment: Sorry, add an example to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deserialise the example input using these classes and this code.

First of all, here is the formatted input:

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "output":{
      "accountNum":".....",
      "customerType":".....",
      "homeNumber":".....",
      "homeIndicator":".....",
      "eligible":true,
      "startDate":"2017-01-01",
      "contactDetails":{
         "firstName":".....",
         "lastName":".....",
         "addressStreet":"....."
      },
      "indicators":[
         "ind1",
         "ind2"
      ],
      "employees":[
         {
            "name":".....",
            "email":".....",
            "model":".....",
            "program":[
               {
                  "name":".....",
                  "date":"....."
               },
               {
                  "name":".....",
                  "date":"....."
               }
            ],
            "type":".....",
            "indicators":[
               "....."
            ],
            "customer":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

These are the classes I used:

```
public class ContactDetails{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String addressStreet;
}

public class Program{
    public String name;
    public String date;
}

public class Employee{
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String model;
    public List<Program> program;
    public String type;
    public List<String> indicators;
    public boolean customer;
}

public class Output{
    public String accountNum;
    public String customerType;
    public String homeNumber;
    public String homeIndicator;
    public boolean eligible;
    public String startDate;
    public ContactDetails contactDetails;
    public List<String> indicators;
    public List<Employee> employees;
}

public class Root{
    public String status;
    public Output output;
}
```

And this is the code I used to deserialise:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Root root = objectMapper.readValue(input2, Root.class);
```

It was pretty simple so Im wondering if I missed something.

Comment: Hi Ali, First thank you for the effort. Appreciate that. In my scenario, I have only two objects (two db tables). The Json is a bit mix meaning some of the attributes in the output level should be map into table b (Employee) like homeNumber. What I did eventually was to init the objects in the constructor and then map all the attributes in the unpackOutput method. Still, I like your answer, and it's also a valid approach.